# Difference between spark.config & spark.conf.set

Tags: apache-spark, configuration

I am using Spark 2.1.0. In this version getting a `SparkSession` is through using a builder, e.g. `SparkSession.builder.app_name().config("some-property", "something-value")`.

Earlier versions used `spark.conf.set("property", "value")`.

Are this `SparkSession.config("property", "value")` and `spark.conf.set("property", "value")` the same? If not, what is the difference?

I also tried:

```
SparkSession.builder.app_name()
  .config("some-property1", "something-value1")
  .config("some-property2", "something-value2")
```

Is this same as the below?

```
spark.conf.set("property1", "value1")
spark.conf.set("property2", "value2")
```